# Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter

Tags: iis-7, web

Hi we have configured IIS with helicon and webgate.

when I am accessing my site I am finding Following Error message on page

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "C:\Appl\Softwares\Webgate\access\oblix\apps\webgate\bin\webgate.dll" failedror
```

Please help.

My configuration as my other environment where all the things are working.

Comment: That usually means the corresponding file does not exist in that path.

Answer (score 18):

Yesterday, while setting up a website on IIS 7 and Windows Server 2008, I loaded up the website in the browser and ended up getting the following error message:

Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter `C:\…isapi.dll` failed

The path was to the `isapi.dll` file in `C:\Program Files\etc` and I was pretty sure everything was setup properly. After doing a bit of research on the topic, I figured out that since I’m running IIS 7 on a 64-bit version of Windows Server and my web application was 32-bit, I had to change a setting in the IIS configuration.

To fix this problem, all you have to do is open IIS7 and click on Application Pools.

Then right-click on the application pool for your website or the default application pool and go to the Advanced Settings tab. Make sure that Enable 32-bit applications is set to True.

That’s it! Now restart IIS and load up Internet Explorer again and your website should load fine.

Comment: This answer was copied and pasted from the following website http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/calling-loadlibraryex-on-isapi-filter/

Comment: Amazing, fixed my issue with Streamtime, for the error : "Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\Web Publishing\publishing-engine\web-server-support\iis\isapi_redirect.dll" failed"

Comment: thank you - that was it - no need to restart IIS - just recycle the application pool in question and it works

Answer (score 6):

I received the same error after installing .NET 1.1.
After uninstalling .NET 1.1 I still had the same error.

However, the error has gone immediately after I went to **IIS Manager -> ISAPI filters** and removed the only filter from here (it was *ASP.NET_4.0.30319.0*).

Answer (score 2):

This error might be because of the following reasons. Those are:

1. webgate installation folder has restricted permissions. Give required permissions for the webgate installation and configuration folder for the IIS process which runs your website. (Had you run configuration script for webgate or just manually configured it?)
2. There may be other DLLs missing on which webgate is dependent. For example, VC++ runtime redistributables. (For 10g use 2005 version, for 11g use 2012 version).
3. Some internal files are missing for webgate. Try re-installing webgate and running config script.